# Lightning element ui:inputDate renders poorly / slow

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Rendering around 50 ui:inputDate elements will seriously slow down the application startup. I have run the profiler and found that iteration with around 50 inputCheckbox and inputTextArea elements renders in 1800ms, while adding ui:inputDate, even without actual object reference in them, will jump to 16000ms. That is almost order of magnitude more.

Has anyone have lightweight implementation or found a workaround?

Not sure if there is any difference, but the application is started in Visualforce by the way. I found [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/97633/3196) which I am not sure how to relate to.

**edit**: tested this outside of VF and results are the same. Below are Chrome's CPU profiler screenshots and sample code to play for your self.

Component source

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:iteration items="1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1" var="asdf" >
        <ui:inputText/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

App source

```
<aura:application >
    <c:Example_component /> 
</aura:application>
```

Screenshot of CPU profile of inputDate elements
[image: Approximately 20 instances of inputDate elements - CPU Profile]

Screenshot of CPU profile of inputText elements
[image: Approximately 20 instances of inputText elements - CPU Profile]

Comment: I have also experienced this. If you look in the lightning inspector Performance tab you'll see the same thing. I've had some luck using a aura:if to hide the input until clicked (inline edit) but aura:if is almost as slow. I'm going to try creating the cmp in javascript or maybe just rolling my own.

Comment: @wellmstein for one of the projects I also had a problem with quite slow dropdown renders. One hack I did is to render options onfocus event. Not exactly solution for this, but might spark some ideas.